# Gravity Forms regex for US ZIP code

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm trying to set up some form validation for a Gravity Form that I've created. One of the fields that I need to validate is a US ZIP code. I want to pass ZIPs that follow the `nnnnn` and `nnnnn-nnnn` patterns. Here's my code:

```
    if ( $field->type == 'address' ) {

    $zip = rgar( $value, $field->id . '.5' );

    if ( preg_match( "(^(?!0{5})(\d{5})(?!-?0{4})(|-\d{4})?$)", $zip ) && ! $field->get_input_property( '5', 'isHidden' )
    ) {
        $result['is_valid'] = false;
        $result['message']  = empty( $field->errorMessage ) ? __( 'Please enter a valid ZIP code (ie. 00000 or 00000-0000).', 'gravityforms' ) : $field->errorMessage;
    } else {
        $result['is_valid'] = true;
        $result['message']  = '';
    }
}
```

My form continues to fail validation and I can't figure out why. I've double checked that `.5` is the correct input field number of the ZIP code. Any suggestions?

My form can be found at http://marcusjones.wpengine.com/

Comment: Try `preg_match('/^(?!0{5})(\d{5})(?!-?0{4})(|-\d{4})$/', $zip, $matches)`. Pay attention to single apostrophes around the regex.

Comment: @stribizhev Still no dice. I'm thinking this is a Gravity Forms specific issue… perhaps syntax? _No_ regex seems to pass validation.

Answer (score 1):

shouldn't be easier to use:

```
/(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)/
```

or other function fe:

```
function isValidPostalCode(postalCode, countryCode) {
switch (countryCode) {
    case "US":
        postalCodeRegex = /^([0-9]{5})(?:[-\s]*([0-9]{4}))?$/;
        break;
    default:
        postalCodeRegex = /^(?:[A-Z0-9]+([- ]?[A-Z0-9]+)*)?$/;
}
return postalCodeRegex.test(postalCode);
}
```

and "if" you'll add quite simple.